# Android: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I'm getting this error:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{amsi.dei.estg.ipleiria.pt.ima/amsi.dei.estg.ipleiria.pt.ima.ListaEmpresas}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference" on this line in my DBHelper:

The error is in this line:

```
database.execSQL(createEmpresasTable);
```

**My DBHelper:**

```
public class ImaBDHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "IMA";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static final String EMPRESAS_TABLE_NAME = "empresas";
private static final String NOME_EMPRESA = "nome";
private static final String DESCRICAO_EMPRESA = "descricao";
private static final String LOCALIDADE_EMPRESA = "localidade";
private static final String AREA_EMPRESA = "area";

private final SQLiteDatabase database;

public ImaBDHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    this.database = getWritableDatabase();
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createEmpresasTable = "CREATE TABLE " + EMPRESAS_TABLE_NAME +
            "(id INTENGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            NOME_EMPRESA + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            DESCRICAO_EMPRESA + " TEXT," +
            LOCALIDADE_EMPRESA + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            AREA_EMPRESA + " TEXT NOT NULL," + ")";
database.execSQL(createEmpresasTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EMPRESAS_TABLE_NAME;
    database.execSQL(sql);
    this.onCreate(database);
}
```

The rest are just methods to create, read, update and delete.

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I haven't found the answer for this exact problem in my searches. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use the `db` object from the signature of `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)`, not the one `database`, you've defined as a field. Same goes for `onUpgrade()` method's implementation...

Comment: Thanks!! Don't know how i didn't notice it

Comment: try to this - check your databases folder name and correct file format name in db , don't copy paste database file in DB Browser for SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` signature value instead from `private final SQLiteDatabase database;`  for execute query like below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createEmpresasTable = "CREATE TABLE " + EMPRESAS_TABLE_NAME +
            "(id INTENGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            NOME_EMPRESA + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            DESCRICAO_EMPRESA + " TEXT," +
            LOCALIDADE_EMPRESA + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            AREA_EMPRESA + " TEXT NOT NULL," + ")";
db.execSQL(createEmpresasTable);// change here
}
```

like this also use in your onUpgrade()

Comment: it is not work me but my problem resolve . try to this - check your databases folder name and correct file format name in db , don't copy paste database file in DB Browser for SQLite